# What are some screen accessibility options for folks who like to read BIG text

Tags: browser, fonts, display, accessibility

I have a hard time reading fonts on webpages, programs and email. I have dropped the resolution down to bump up the text and noticed an improvement in reading comprehension. I can alt+scroll wheel in browsers to bump up the text but... I'm looking to see what other options I have out there...

If you have any suggestions related to accessibility and displays I'm all ears!

OS: Windows 7
Also have a Mac, OSX Mtn Lion

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: There are settings for font size in the system controls that should be changed before one uses the screen resolution method.

Comment: @DanD. I did see the font size adjustment panel in: Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display

Comment: Evertime I see "Set custom text size (DPI)" I expect it to do something with setting the DPI **on the display**. And to do nothing with fonts whatsoever. MS should rename it to 'Show everything on display at XXX %'.  (Crosses fingers for win9).

Comment: @hennes - totally, this method seemed to help in some instances, but yeah, I picked the middle of the road option and my fonts are tiny in the context menu's and some windows and tabs... what? why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no computer with OS/X. Hopefully someone else can answer that. But for the windows 7 system:

1. Set the resolution to what is native for your LCD. (Non native resolutions usually yields a fuzzy picture. And that is harder to read).
2. Then right click on an empty place of the desktop.
3. Select the option "screen resolution"
4. A new window will open. Near the bottom is a "Make text and other items larger of smaller". Select that.
5. A new window will open. Select "Larger - 150%" and click OK. You will need to reboot.

This *should* make everything on your display 1½ times as large, yet keep the sharpness of the LCD.

[image: Screen resolution selection]
[image: Screen resolution panel]
[image: Select DPI]

If that is still too small, then use the option "Set custum text size (DPI)" on the left of the third screen.

All decently written programs will work just fine with this. Sadly some are not well well written and/or do not adhere to the standards for windows programs. Those might show text outside windows.

Comment: Exactly. This method is what I was going to mention.

Answer (score 3):

One idea for OS X is to hold control and then scroll with your mouse. This will zoom in and out on part of your screen. You can zoom out by scrolling the opposite way.

Answer (score 1):

Win7 also has a magnifier that doubles the size of the selected part of the screen. 
Type *magnifier* in the search box to get to the accessibility screen to switch it on. 
Then search *magnifier* again, right click the application and pin it to taskbar. It's now available when you need it.
Either the "lens" or "docked" options seem to be most useful.